# While loop after 1st iteration is not updating array values

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to code cyclic sort and following is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int temp = 0;
    int[] nums = new int[]{4,2,1,3};
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
      while(nums[i]!=nums[nums[i]-1]){
        // line#8
        System.out.println(nums[i] + " " + nums[nums[i]-1]);
        temp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[nums[i]-1];
        nums[nums[i]-1] = temp;
      }
    }

    for(int i:nums){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

After 1st iteration in while loop:
i=0, nums[] = {3,2,1,4}. But after 1st iteration in while loop, if nums[0]=3, then nums[nums[0]-1] = 1, which is not the case i.e. nums[nums[0]-1] = 4. Also, this code will run into infinite loop and elements 3 & 4 will keep swapping.

Could someone explain me why while loop is not interpreting nums[nums[0]-1] as 1?

TIA

Comment: The value of i is not changed within a while loop and remains the same. Hence infinite loop.

Comment: Hi, the value of i is meant to be constant until the element at index i is equal to I+1. So, if the condition is not met, keep swapping elements. And shouldn't nums[nums[I]-1] be 1 after 1st iteration?

Comment: Check this article: [Cycle Sort - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cycle-sort/), for understanding the implementation.

Comment: Thanks @MushifAliNawaz, I saw the other implementation, but I am really trying to understand why while loop is not updating appropriately?

Comment: @Rohan the reason is that the value of `i` is not updating. So it will keep replacing `3` with `4` and `4` with `3` resulting in an infinite loop. Value of `i` is always `0` here.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz Yes, I understand i is not updating, but nums[0] = 3 after 1st while loop iteration, so shouldn't nums[nums[0]-1] = nums[3-1] = nums[2] = 1? And I should keep i=0 until index 0's value is matched, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revised your code it will work. you should store nums[i] - 1 value before you change nums[i].

```
    int temp = 0;
    int[] nums = new int[]{4, 2, 1, 3, 6, 8, 5, 7};
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        while (nums[i] != nums[nums[i] - 1]) {
            temp = nums[i];
            int index = nums[i] - 1;
            nums[i] = nums[nums[i] - 1];
            nums[index] = temp;
        }
    }

    for (int i : nums) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```